# C# Calling same function on Subclasses

Tags: c#, inheritance

C# **Simplified** example.

Have a class hierarchy: `Animal -> Pet -> Dog`

Each class has a `Eat()` method that does something specific to that hierarchy level.

When I call `Dog.Eat()` I need `Pet.Eat()` then `Animal.Eat()` to be called in that order.

I have tried adding to all the subclasses:

```
 public override void Eat() {
    base.Eat();
 }
```

and on the base `Animal`:

```
 public virtual void Eat(){

 }
```

This doesn't seem right as I get the warning that I should use the 'new' keyword on `Dog.Eat()` as it hides base `Eat()`

Comment: Did you use `override` for `Dog`'s `Eat()` too?

Comment: The "simplified example" is too simplified.  You claim to have three classes, show three complete classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `override` on  `Pet` and `Dog`  class.

then use `base.Eat();` on subclass method.

```
public class Animal 
{
    public virtual void Eat()
    {
       Console.WriteLine( "A" ); 
    }
}

public class Pet : Animal
{
    public override void Eat()
    {
        base.Eat();
        Console.WriteLine( "B" );
    }
}

public class Dog : Pet 
{
    public override void Eat()
    {
        base.Eat();
        Console.WriteLine( "C" );
    }
}
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vq824P)

Comment: hi. is there a way to not call `base.Eat()` on every override? or should I say  call it **automatically**? like some sort of implementation